# onLongClick() is not called on long-click action

Tags: android, floating, onlongclicklistener, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to implement a floating context menu in my application. I'm following an example provided by google: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html ,but stuck at the beginning with that piece of code:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

new AsyncTaskOne(this).execute();

     getListView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            // Called when the user long-clicks on someView

            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Log.v("OnLongClick", "clicked");    // It doesn't log anything on a long click event.
                if (mActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
                mActionMode = actiV().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                view.setSelected(true);
                return true;
            }
        });

 }
```

I've put Log checking into `onLongClick(View view)` method to find out if it's actually called. When I long-click some item from my ListView nothing happens (my `Log.v` doesn't log anything). I'm wondering maybe the tutorial is missing something (some declaration in layout.xml)?

Comment: Is there anything in your `ListView`, or is it empty? Does it fill the content area even though its empty? Otherwise there wouldn't be a place to touch it...

Comment: `new AsyncTaskOne(this).execute();` is populating the ListView before `setOnLongClickListener` is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You setting the long click listener to the whole listview, Did you really want to set an OnItemLongClick which would get the long click for an item in the list?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html